# jQuery's attr() function breaks html with html special characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please take a look at the following code:

http://jsfiddle.net/htdTg/2/

In the first link there is a title attribute containing the html special character `&lt;` followed by "!" (it doesn't matter which character it is followed by actually).
When we take the value of that title attribute with jQuery's attr() function the html is broken (you can see that there is no "<" character printed as long as the following text is also missing.

In the second link the only difference is that I have added a space after `&lt;` and now it works as expected.

Do you think it's a bug in jQuery or I just don't understand something?

PS. If you think I'm doing something strange - it's just some piece of code from some tooltip plugin.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" title="<div style='color:red'>This is the less than sign: &lt;! Now you know it?</div>">This is a link</a><br>
<a href="#" title="<div style='color:red'>This is the less than sign: &lt; ! Now you know it?</div>">This is a link</a><br>​
```

jQuery:

```
$('a').each(function() {
    $('body').append($(this).attr('title')); });

// just to exclude that it's append() function's fault :)
$('body').append("<div style='color:red'>This is the less than sign: &lt;! Now you know it?</div>");​
```

Comment: Is it valid to include HTML code in attributes?

Comment: I added your code from jsFiddle.  Questions and Answers on SO should be fully "self-contained".

Comment: The title should not contain any HTML. Some people actually do hover the links, and see the code.

Comment: Did you see the W3C standard? See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13847609/376535

Comment: @Blender No, it is not valid to include HTML code in attributes. And that is the correct answer. Not escaping.

Comment: @ErikE: It's valid to include *escaped* code in attributes.

Comment: @Blender Of course it is valid. It's also "valid" to display your entire web page in raw (escaped) HTML and expect the user to save it as HTML and *then* view the result. But it is hardly correct in the sense of doing something sensible, useful, or practical for professional web development.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is pretty interesting. I looked up what text can be in a [`title` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-cdata) and the reference says:

> User agents should interpret attribute values as follows:
>
> 1. **Replace character entities with characters,**
> 2. Ignore line feeds,
> 3. Replace each carriage return or tab with a single space.

Apparently, this is the expected behavior. `&lt;` is being parsed as `<` by the browser, which might be interpreted as HTML by jQuery.

You should be escape the ampersand as well:

```
&amp;lt;
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/htdTg/9/**

**Even better demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PsZeY/6/**

Comment: If you're supposed to escape ampersands that are part of a valid character entity encoding, then how can you put an ampersand in there as part of a character entity encoding?

Comment: But then you have an *unescaped ampersand* in there. So you should do `&amp;amp;amp;lt;`. But, still unescaped! So `&amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;`. Wait--`&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;`. No, `&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;`. AUUUGH! The question is WHY the double escaping? If the rule is, as you say, `Replace character entities with characters` then how is `&lt;` not doing the job? *It's been escaped.*

Comment: @ErikE: Not really. The browser replaces character entities with their respective characters while it parses your HTML. You're just escaping twice so that the value that you retrieve is the unescaped version of your twice escaped code, which is escaped only once.

Comment: @ErikE: `title` attributes expect data to be of the format that I linked to in my answer. Since you are expecting escaped content, you escape the string two times, as the browser will unescape it once. It's done by the parser: http://jsfiddle.net/htdTg/10/

Comment: Okay, I figured out the problem. Your answer is technically right for the asked question, but overall a wrong answer when viewed from the whole perspective of best-practice web development. Stay tuned for my own answer, coming shortly.

Comment: @ErikE: Care to explain how? I've never had to put HTML into tooltips so I don't know *why* you would need to do this, but there isn't anything inherently wrong with doing it.

Comment: @ErikE: That's not the point of the question. The question is about why the attribute's value changes as it passes from the parser to your script or stylesheet. Even if you were doing this "correctly", the same problems arise: http://jsfiddle.net/htdTg/13/

Answer (score 3):

### Why its happening?

This is happening because `&lt;! Now you know it? </div>` is converted to `<! Now you know it? </div-->`

**According to HTML standard** `<!` and `>` is the start and end of **comment structure**. Note this is comment structure **not comment**. Hence browwer converts the rest as comment unless it gets a end delimiter `>`.

From [**W3C**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.4)

> ```
> <!-- this is a comment -->
> <!-- and so is this one,
>     which occupies more than one line -->
> ```
>
> White space is not permitted between the **markup declaration open** delimiter(`<!`) and the comment open delimiter (`--`), but is permitted between the comment close delimiter (`--`) and the **markup declaration close** delimiter (">"). A common error is to include a string of hyphens (`---`) within a comment. Authors should avoid putting two or more adjacent hyphens inside comments.

Also in [here](http://www.flightlab.com/~joe/sgml/comments.html)

> The syntax for comment declarations in SGML is
>
> ```
>  comment declaration =
>     MDO ("<!"), (comment, ( s | comment )* )?, MDC (">")
>  comment =
>     COM ("--"), SGML character*, COM ("--")
> ```

### How to solve it?

You already know it. use `&amp;` to replace `&`. So write `&amp;lt;!` instead of `&lt;!`. This will make `&lt;` appended to body element instead of `<!` which is comment structure opening.

Comment: The question is not how to make it work, it's why in this current shape and form it does not.

Comment: @KingKongFrog added the *Why*

Comment: You still didn't answer the ultimate *why*--you answered the proximate why of the `<!` starting an HTML comment. But why would an attribute need to be double-encoded? It's only because the OP is cramming HTML into a place it doesn't belong.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're just asking the question or actually looking for a solution to the problem. If the latter, then strangely this seems to work fine: `&amp;lt;`

Updated code:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" title="<div style='color:red'>This is the less than sign: &amp;lt;! Now you know it?</div>">This is a link</a><br>
<a href="#" title="<div style='color:red'>This is the less than sign: &amp;lt; ! Now you know it?</div>">This is a link</a><br>​
```

jQuery:

```
$('a').each(function() {
    $('body').append($(this).attr('title')); });

// just to exclude that it's append() function's fault :)
$('body').append("<div style='color:red'>This is the less than sign: &lt;! Now you know it?</div>");​
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/htdTg/3/

Comment: Then it looks like a bug in jQuery to me. Try filing it and link to the question, please. I want to see the official response.

Comment: @JanDvorak, you can always go and ask yourself in the IRC channel ;)

Comment: There's no jQuery bug. It's using *text* as *HTML* that is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The text isn't missing the problem is that it get commented because `&lt;!` is the same of `<!` which is being translated to `<!--`(don't know why) which starts a comment in `html`.

If you inspect your html you'll see the following.

```
<div style='color:red'>This is the less than sign: <!-- Now you know it? --></div>
<div style='color:red'>This is the less than sign: < ! Now you know it?</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case...

```
title="<div style='color:red'>This is the less than sign: &lt;! Now you know it?</div>"
```

`&lt;!` is converted to `<!` which is the start of a HTML comment and exactly why it does not render in the browser window.

For all cases, you should not have HTML entities contained within an attribute.  Use this instead...

```
title="&lt;div style='color:red'&gt;This is the less than sign: &amp;lt;! Now you know it?&lt;/div&gt;"
```

​
http://jsfiddle.net/htdTg/5/

If you want to preserve the HTML entities, use `&lt;div&gt;` to be *processed* as `<div>`.  Alternatively, `&amp;lt;div&amp;gt;` will actually *render* `<div>` in the browser window.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/htdTg/8/

So if you want the browser to actually display a `<!`, then use this: `&amp;lt!`

Comment: So, just to be safe, if encoding attributes programmatically, shouldn't all the `&lt;` characters be `&amp;lt;`? It is sneakily nasty that a character following an entity can determine how that entity is represented.

Comment: @ErikE, that depends on what you're trying to do.  See the difference here:  http://jsfiddle.net/htdTg/8/

Comment: You answered the question but didn't address the more important issue that the OP *shouldn't be doing that*.

Comment: @ErikE, huh?  Maybe you missed this line?  _"For all cases, you should **not** have HTML entities contained within an attribute"_

Comment: It was not "how to escape entities" that concerned me but "putting HTML in title attributes at all, escaped or not".

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is really wrong..

The issue is that html inside attributes must be encoded. You already have encoded the `<` as `&lt;` and that means that it will be read as `<`.

So `.attr()`  will return a pure `<` character and not the encoded..

<strike>The reason it does not show is with `.append` which will try to parse the html if it thinks there is html in it.. It finds the `<!` text and it considers it as html comment.</strike> ***actually this is done directly by the browser***.

---

If you look at

```
var e = document.createElement('div');
e.innerHTML = '<!';
console.log(e.innerHTML);
```

you will see that the inner HTML of the div after setting it to `<!` is `<!---->`.

So that is how the browsers interpret this code.. it has nothing to do with jQuery..

Comment: +1 for `append` information. I investigated and it realy happen on `append`.

Comment: Do you know why `<!` is considered as start of a comment ?

Comment: @RicardoLohmann because html comments start with `<!--` and end with `-->`. Browsers will translate `<!` to comment.. updated answer to show example