# jQuery - attr function can't show special character

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm building project with .Net MVC and jQuery. The text i want to set as title comes from my resources file. But it can't show spesical characters.

Here is how i set it:

```
    @if (Model.ConfigService.Current.Customer.ShowOrdinaryTimeScore) {                
        <text>
            $(".match_time .time_played").html('@SharedStrings.MatchResultShort');
            $(".match_time .time_played").attr("title", "@SharedStrings.FullTimeResult");
        </text>
    }
```

SharedStrings.FullTimeResult contains a "Ç" character. And my html becomes:

```
<h3 class="time_played" title="'Ma&amp;#231; Sonucu">MS</h3>
```

as you can see my Ç character has become

> &#231;

How can i fix this?

Comment: you need to use `@Html.Raw(SharedStrings.FullTimeResult)`

Comment: html encode the string before adding it to the attribute

Comment: See Blender answer here [link][1] hope this will help.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847485/jquerys-attr-function-breaks-html-with-html-special-characters